# Code coverage only covering one test instead of all suite

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I'm trying to get my code coverage report to cover all of my laravel application code ( Controllers and Models ). For some reason it is only covering one test. Is there something wrong with this configuration below?

```xml
<phpunit colors="true"
         bootstrap="/Users/bob/projects/leonardo2/laravel/cli/tasks/test/phpunit.php"
         backupGlobals="false">
  
  <testsuites>
    <testsuite name="Test Suite">
                        <directory suffix=".test.php">/Users/bob/projects/leonardo2/application/tests</directory>
                  </testsuite>
  </testsuites>
  
  <filter>
    <blacklist>       
        <exclude>
          <directory suffix=".test.php">/Users/bob/projects/leonardo2/application/tests</directory>
        </exclude>
    </blacklist>
    <whitelist>
      <exclude>
        <directory suffix=".php">/Users/bob/projects/leonardo2/application/config</directory>       
        <directory suffix=".php">/Users/bob/projects/leonardo2/application/views</directory>
        <directory suffix=".php">/Users/bob/projects/leonardo2/application/migrations</directory>
        <directory suffix=".php">/Users/bob/projects/leonardo2/application/libraries</directory>
        <directory suffix=".php">/Users/bob/projects/leonardo2/application/tasks</directory>
        <directory suffix=".php">/Users/bob/projects/leonardo2/application/language</directory>
      </exclude>
    </whitelist>
  </filter>

   <logging>
      <log type="coverage-html" target="./storage/work/report/" charset="UTF-8"
       highlight="false" lowUpperBound="35" highLowerBound="70"/>
    </logging>
</phpunit>
```

Comment: have you tried paring back your phpunit.xml file to basics to see if it includes everything? Also, I don't think aboslute paths are required, and it breaks if others try to run your tests.

Answer (score 3):

So much complex conditioning is not needed I guess. Just add the app directory in the whitelist under filter tag.

```
<filter>
    <whitelist>
        <directory suffix=".php">app/</directory>
    </whitelist>
</filter>
```

follow this link for a better understanding.
[Add Code Coverage Report to Laravel Project](https://coderwall.com/p/mxtqiw/add-code-coverage-report-to-laravel-project)